# Windows Scheduled Task 15 minutes past and 15 minutes to the hour

Tags: c#, powershell

I am creating a scheduled task in powershell. I want the trigger to be every 15 minutest to the hour and 15 minutes past the hour.

Fx:

```
00:15
00:45
01:15
01:45
..
23:15
23:45
```

How do I accomplish this with a New-ScheduledTaskTrigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

You need to define it to have a RepetitionInterval and RepetitionDuration to get it to repeat.

I was unable to figure out how to set an `Indefinite` duration for the repeat, but I got it to repeat until 2036 by doing:

```
$span = New-TimeSpan -End "2036-01-01"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 00:15 -RepetitionInterval 00:30 -RepetitionDuration $span
```

And then registering the task.

Comment: Ok, but if I register the task at fx 8 am, will the first run then be at 08:15 or 00:15 the following day?

Comment: It will start at `08:15` i.e. as soon as the trigger condition becomes true. The `-At` option is parsed and says starting today at 00:15, so once the clock hits 08:15, or 08:45 the task will trigger. You can experiment with this using a benign task such as launching Cmd as the current logged in user to see it happening.

Comment: Thank you Petesh. I just tried it out, and it seems to work as intended

Comment: -RepetitionDuration  ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)